# Stock prices rise due to index (SP500) inclusion means I should not buy index funds?

Tags: stocks, index-fund, stock-valuation, market-indexes

When a stock rises (either temporarily or permanently) before its inclusion into an index, that means index funds need to be purchasing the stock at inflated prices.

1. Doesn't that mean when you purchase index funds, you are significantly overpaying for some stocks?
2. Shouldn't you purchase some stocks that's just outside the SP500 so that when they're added you can make a gain?

Comment: There's a lot of new demand due to inclusion into index, which may affect the price momentarily. Usually it sorts itself out.

Comment: @littleadv that doesn't make sense

Comment: what doesn't? The new demand comes from the fact that the stock is included in the index - all the index funds will buy into it, automatically, so at the short term it spikes demand. But these buyers will hold no matter what as long as the stock remains in the index, so this demand is very short term.

Comment: @littleadv the demand may be short term but it doesn't matter because the index funds will buy it at that elevated price. If they wait until the stock price went back down to purchase your explanation would make sense

Comment: They don't buy all at once, different funds rebalance on different schedules. So yes, they do wait

Comment: @littleadv If it's known when they will purchase it's easy to just buy sometime before their purchase and sell immediately. Why isn't that done?

Comment: Isn't it? I thought that was the premise of your question

Comment: @littleadv Right, so for example if VOO rebalances at Jan 1, then prices should rise before Dec 31. Then VOO purchases at elevated prices.

Comment: @littleadv so yeah it sorts itself out but the fund still buys at the elevated prices, as I said.

Comment: "if VOO rebalances at Jan 1, then prices should rise before Dec 31. Then VOO purchases at elevated prices" Only if the market knows this, and that VOO actually buys the stock on Jan 1. It may wait until Jan 3 to actually buy the stock and either accept some tracking error or mitigate the risk with derivatives (if it can). The tracking error would be very small since new inclusions are a very small part of the index.

Answer (score 6):

> Doesn't that mean when you purchase index funds, you are significantly overpaying for some stocks?

I think "significantly" is a bit of an overstatement (it's not like stocks double when their inclusion is announced), and the vast majority of index fund buyers are not trying to "time the market" but are investing long term, so the future growth would far outweigh the slightly larger cost basis. In addition, since these indexes are market cap weighted, new entries make up a very small portion (e.g. much less than 1/500 of the S&P 500) of the index, so the initial bump in price has a very minor on the value of the index.

> Shouldn't you purchase some stocks that's just outside the SP500 so that when they're added you can make a gain?

You can try - and this is called "Index Front Running". You can do some research and see how effective the strategy is. My research has shown that Index Trackers have largely caught up with this strategy and try to avoid it by changing exactly when they buy, even at the expense of some temporary tracking error.

Note that not all stocks "just outside the index" get added, so you will largely be guessing on what stocks will actually be included. You will be right on some and wrong on others.

I'm not saying it's a *bad* strategy, but since it is a known effect, much of it will already be "priced in", and there's less opportunity to capitalize on it.

Comment: If you think up a neat "hack" to beat the market, chances are someone else has already thought it up too, and there's a whole niche industry trying to make it work. -- And if it does work, other investors will start pricing it into their models, and it will stop being "niche" and become part of the standard. Even a truly novel "hack" only works for the short term.

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't you purchase some stocks that's just outside the SP500 so
> that when they're added you can make a gain?

Of course you have no idea when that stock will be added. But if you want to try and time the market, by guessing that a change is imminent, and then buying shares, and selling on the spike; that is a method.

> Doesn't that mean when you purchase index funds, you are significantly
> overpaying for some stocks?

Lets say this is a weakness of investing in an index fund. And lets also assume that your proposed idea is valid and would work. Still over the long term active funds under-perform the index funds. So I don't think there is a fund manager making significant use of this idea.

If a index fund is exactly following the index then they won't purchase shares in non-index companies until the index changes; but if the fund doesn't exactly follow the index they could wait until the spike in price dissipates, and then buy the shares.